# Facebook open graph object with link

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to create a custom open graph story. I would like to make the action related object clickable. For now it's just text.
[image]

This is what I want to achieve
[image]

I was playing with custom objects and built ones but the result was the same. Created object has a url property but it is still displayed as plain text. How to achieve something like on the second picture?

```
{
  "end_time": "2016-05-16T10:48:38+0000",
  "start_time": "2016-05-16T10:48:38+0000",
  "type": "serviceloverstestapp:review",
  "data": {
    "article": {
      "id": "00000000000000",
      "title": "My title",
      "type": "article",
      "url": "http://foo.bar"
    }
  },
  "id": "1111111111111"
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In the facebook object-browser the `og:url` property is blank but on the scraped page `og:url` tag is present. After filling it in object-browser and saving without any error the url still remains blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some serious digging I have found a solution. In the open graph action in `edit tenses` view I had to change my object reference in `One to One - Without Object Title` section to `{article}` not `{article.name}` or anything like that.